# Facebook share text

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, share

I have these links on my site

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://site.com/profile/4')" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://site.com/profile/5')" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://site.com/profile/8')" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://site.com/profile/9')" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" class="fb_share_button" onclick="return fbs_click('http://site.com/profile/10')" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"></a>
```

with this javascript

```
<script>
function fbs_click(location_place) {
        u=location_place;
        t=document.title;
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and i want to know if there is a way to add text or some sort to each one uniquely so that each link as a different body ..here is my code [working](http://mediaclear.net/mark/test.php) but where and how do i add a description of some sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) tags to the pages that you wish to share - that's how the sharer picks them up, and the nice thing is that if someone decides to just share a link in their feed the same information is picked up. The [Facebook URL Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) is a great tool for figuring out what Facebook sees when it's looking for Open Graph information.

Comment: but how do i use multiple on one page as you can see from my example i have a few

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Read the OP wrong... 
As far as I know/have found, you can't adjust the body text of what gets displayed in the share dialog using facebook.com/sharer.php. You may have to look into the other methods of social interaction with facebook api.

Comment: I know how to use all those ...but where on the http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php? do i set it

Comment: OH! Sorry I read your question wrong. As far as I know, you can't adjust the body text of a share using facebook.com/sharer.php. At least I haven't found a way to do it yet...

Answer (score 0):

If my memory is good, you can add a parameter in the facebook.com/sharer.php? url like so :

facebook.com/sharer.php?u=yourlinke&t=The text you want it to be in the textarea

Comment: t is not for text. It's for the title.